# Sqlite Cursor Window allocation 2048 kb failed

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-sqlite

```
  public List<Diagnosis_tble> GetAllPatientDetails()
     {
      List<Diagnosis_tble> DiagnosistblList = new   ArrayList<Diagnosis_tble>();  
      String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_Diagnosistble + "";  
      SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
      Cursor cursor = null;

       {  
        cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

      if(cursor.getCount() > 0)
      {
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) 

         do{     
            Diagnosis_tble  diagCreation_tble = new Diagnosis_tble(); 

             diagCreation_tble.SetDiagnosisID(cursor.getString(0));
             diagCreation_tble.SetPName(cursor.getString(1));
             diagCreation_tble.SetHospitalNo(cursor.getString(2));
             diagCreation_tble.SetPGender(cursor.getString(3));
             diagCreation_tble.SetPacemaker(cursor.getString(4));
             diagCreation_tble.SetDiagType(cursor.getString(5));
             diagCreation_tble.SetP_Age(cursor.getString(6));
             diagCreation_tble.SetDeviceID(cursor.getString(7));
             diagCreation_tble.SetDiagStrtTime(cursor.getString(8));
             diagCreation_tble.SetDiagEndTime(cursor.getString(9));
             diagCreation_tble.SetDiagStatus(cursor.getString(10));
             diagCreation_tble.SetReportStatus(cursor.getString(11));
             diagCreation_tble.SetUploadStatus(cursor.getString(12));

          DiagnosistblList.add(diagCreation_tble); 

         }while (cursor.moveToNext());

          return DiagnosistblList; 
      }else
      {
          return null;
      } 
    }
    finally
    {
        cursor.close();
    }
}
```

what is wrong in this code?

I am getting this Exception:

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity 
 ComponentInfo{com.abc.TestApp/com.abc.TestApp.LoadData}:
 android.database.CursorWindowAllocationException: Cursor window allocation of 2048 kb failed.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have faced the same trouble as you. What I did is I went all over my application data classes and close all other cursor objects which were not closed. so I guess same happen in your application also, open your data classes and find the cursors that didn't closed and close them

Comment: can you check my above code? Am I missing somewhere? Can you correct it please?

Comment: normally mobile devices not allow to load huge amount of data to its memory, so I guess you are load huge data.. can you re check it by filtering some columns instead of loading all the columns and all the data. just load few records and see...
I'm checking your code again.. :) wait

Comment: Declare the following as a global variable

Comment: What was the issue...what did you done for overcome it??

Comment: Make sure you are closing all of your cursor in each and every function. This is only reason to get this exception.Thats how I overcome with this issue.